# Two tuples as one element in python list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am now getting used to python lists. But I encountered a complicated list and I have troubles parsing it.

```
prediction=[('__label__inflation_today', 0.8),('__label__economic_outlook', 0.2)]
```

I am trying to present this prediction in a better way, something like excel.

```
predicted label              probability
Inflation_today              0.8
Economic_outlook             0.2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is [`pandas DataFrame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#dataframe), 
then use [`Series.str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
import pandas as pd
prediction=[('__label__inflation_today', 0.8), ('__label__economic_outlook', 0.2)] 
df = pd.DataFrame(prediction, columns=['predicted label',' probability'])

df['predicted label'] = df['predicted label'].str.replace('__label__', '')

print (df)
    predicted label   probability
0   inflation_today           0.8
1  economic_outlook           0.2
```

If need only data use [`DataFrame.to_string`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_string.html):

```
print (df.to_string(index=False, header=None))
inflation_today  0.8
economic_outlook  0.2
```

Comment: can we remove "underscore underscore label underscore underscore" using pandas?

Comment: ..yeah, If I can trim '__label__'., that would be great

Comment: `label` is column name, it is meta information like `0,1` called index.

Comment: I typed a mistake in the question. I have prediction=[[('__label__inflation_today', 0.8),('__label__economic_outlook', 0.2)]]. I apologize for this.

Comment: I see it, give em a sec.

Comment: Solution is  `df = pd.DataFrame(prediction[0], columns=['predicted label',' probability'])`

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
for x in prediction:
   string=x[0].replace('__label__','')
   print(string,":",x[1])

inflation_today : 0.8
economic_outlook : 0.2
```

If you want to access it using those names, you can also create a dictionary

```
d={}
for x in prediction:
   string=x[0].replace('__label__','')
   d[string]=x[1]

d
{'economic_outlook': 0.2, 'inflation_today': 0.8}

d['economic_outlook']
0.2
```

Comment: `dict[string]=x[1]` results in a `TypeError`. I think you meant to set it to `d`.

Comment: @srig Yes, made the change